# Rails could not find gem, found in bundle show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

So if I try to start my server I get the error

```
Could not find abstract-1.0.0 in any of the sources
Try running bundle install.
```

I run that and I get

```
Using abstract (1.0.0)
```

Furthermore running a bundle show abstract gives me the correct path for the gem. That path is also referenced in gem env.

I'm really not sure how it can't be found...

Answer (score 0):

You might have conflicting installations of ruby. One with the proper gem which you are using in the shell but one the server is using which doesn't have it installed properly.

I would check your environment variables to see if there is a conflict.

This can also happen if you are using RVM and have switched to a different version/gemset than the default one.

Answer (score 0):

What command are you using to start the server?

If `rails server` is what is giving you the error, I recommend trying: `bundle exec rails server`

If that's not the issue, another question that might help troubleshoot; are you using rvm? What does `rvm info` give you?